# issue with countdown in NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, setinterval

Good morning all

I'm having a problem with a countdown code with NodeJS, I'm currently working with express and my code is below:

```
 router.get("/", (req, res) => {

    let remaining = setInterval(function () {
        time = 30 - Math.floor((new Date().getTime() / 1000.0) % 30);
        console.log(time);
    }, 1000);

    res.render("index", { title: "Website title", remaining }); //Balise Title
});
```

I don't know why but the countdown is not working instead I have this display **[object object]**.

Strange thing my countdown is working fine in console.log ...
Thank you for your help

Comment: What do you expect to return in response? 'remaining' is only an id of the timer returned from setinterval.

Comment: you are returning the `setInterval` not the time. also this dosnt work in any way because your render just once. you need put the render function inside `setInterval` but this dosnt work either  because you send the rendered content also just once to the client. Bad practice. If you really want a server based countdown, switch to websockets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const io = require('socket.io')();
// or
const Server = require('socket.io');
const io = new Server();
io.on('connect',(socket)=>{
 setInterval(function () {
     
        let time = 30 - Math.floor((new Date().getTime() / 1000.0) % 30);
        socket.emit('get_time',time)
    }, 1000)
    })
```

On the front end import io from SocketIO --
https://socket.io/docs/

```
const socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
  socket.on('get_time', (time)=>{
             console.log(time)
           });
```

Comment: TypeError: remaining is not a function, on close you should clear/stop the interval with `clearInterval`

Comment: Thank you Ankush Verma, that work ! I was an issue with "Express Generator", this link help me too , to configure Express Generator : 
[link]( https://onedesigncompany.com/news/express-generator-and-socket-io )

Answer (score -1):

Try this code below:

```
 router.get("/", (req, res) => {

    var time;
    let remaining = setInterval(function () {
        time = 30 - Math.floor((new Date().getTime() / 1000.0) % 30);
        console.log(time);
    }, 1000);
   res.render("index", { title: "Website title", time }); //Balise Title
});
```

Comment: Dosnt work, `time` is undfined when `res.render` is called and even not updated at all.